# C++ library to asp.net

Tags: c++, asp.net, dll, hyperlink

I want to use a C++ library for my asp.net website.
I don't know how to make a .dll of the library and make it work.
I tried making a dll and import it to asp.net.
Do I need a to do something in the c++ code for the dll to work?

Source code: http://warp.povusers.org/FunctionParser/fparser.html

Answer (score 1):

have u tried linking it in this way?

```
[DllImport("C:\\Users\\pieter\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\WebSites\\Algorithm\\MathFuncDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern double Multiply(double a, double b);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are 2 ways to "expose" your C++ library to .NET:

- Static(Compile time): Create a C++/CLI wrapper or
- Dynamic: Create a C# wrapper that calls your C++ .dll using PInvoke.

For more info see e.g. code project: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/651516/Exposing-native-to-managed-Cplusplus-CLI-vs-P-Invo

After this make sure that you place your C++ .dll NOT in the ASP.NET\bin directory. Believe me this can cause lots of trouble I've been there.